# How to import sql via shell in Python?

Tags: python, mysql

I have case :

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', unix_socket='/opt/lampp/var/mysql/mysql.sock', user='root', passwd=None, db='test')
cur = conn.cursor()
cur.execute("test < /mypath/test.sql")
cur.close()
conn.close()
```

I always get error :

```
1064 , "You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'test < /mypath/test.sql' at line 1"
```

I tried to use `source` and it still failed. Did you know why?

Thank you.

Comment: Simply because it is not a valid SQL command, but only valid for the MySQL command line interface...

Answer (score 1):

Your error message says that the MySQL server can't understand

```
 test < /mypath/test.sql' at line 1
```

If you're a long time *nix user, it seems intuitive that you should be able to use commands like this to pass various sorts of data streams to various programs. But that's not the way the Python sql API (or most language-specific) sql APIs works.

You need to pass a valid SQL query to the `execute()` method in the API, so the API can pass it to the database server.  A vaild query will be something like `INSERT` or `CREATE TABLE`.

Look, the server might be on a different host machine, so telling the server to read from `/mypath/test.sql` is very likely a meaningless instruction to that server. Even if it did understand it, it might say `File test.sql not found.`

The `mysql(1)` command line client software package can read commands from files. Is that what you want?

Comment: my file test.sql can be accessed from terminal. If I use shell in terminal, you can import database use 'test < /mypath/test.sql' or 'source /mypath/test.sql'. It's failed when I using SQL in PHPMyAdmin or access from my python code. I still don't know why.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> import MySQLdb
>>> db = MySQLdb.connect(host = 'demodb', user = 'root', passwd = 'root', db = 'mydb')
>>> cur = db.cursor()
>>> cur.execute('select * from mytable')
>>> rows = cur.fetchall()
```

Install MySQL-Python package to use MySQLdb.